# UIViewController text won't be displayed after performSegue

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a view in the storyBoard with a button saying "You are cool". After calling that view with `performSegue` the view appears but the button text is not there. When I programmatically set the value of the text to "You are cool" in `viewWillAppear` still nothing happens. But if the text which I define programatically does not match with that in the MainStoryBoard the text is display. What could cause that strange behaviour ?

**EDIT:**

I encountered with the same problem again. Here is my code snippet I am using :

```
@IBAction func loginAction(_ sender: Any) {
         print("loginIsExecuting")
         Server.Login(email: inputEmail.text!, password: inputPassword.text!, handlerDone:{
                print("Logged in successfully")
            }, handlerFailed: {
                print("===Failed to log in ")
                self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            })
}
```

After handlerFailed the text appears in the console, but the background is changed after some time (generally 30 seconds)

Comment: show a storyboard, did you set correct constraints?

Comment: Yes, also when I tap the button the text appears

Comment: show code then, youcan also inspect your view while running in xcode to see where is your text

Answer (score 0):

please first check your Button Font Color and Button Background Color.. If this will not helpful then share your code..

Answer (score 0):

I feel button title is not properly set. Please make sure you are using setLabel for button title set.

Ex :`[btnName setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];`

Answer (score 0):

Using DispatchQueue.main.sync solved my problem

```
Server.Login(email: inputEmail.text!, password: inputPassword.text!,       handlerDone:{
        print("Logged in successfully")

    }, handlerFailed: {
        print("===Failed to log in ")
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.rer
        }
    })
```